# how do I check if SSL_write is possible?

Tags: ssl

How do I check if it is possible to write to the SSL stream using `SSL_write()`?

I need something like

```
  if(SSL_write_possible(ssl))
        SSL_write();
```

Comment: which language are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to do non-blocking I/O with OpenSSL. If that's the case, I would suggest you use SSL_get_wfd() and select() in order to detect when the underlying file descriptor is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is I do have async IO, but I use buffers now and write to SSL which writes to BIO and then I read from BIO and write to another async stream. I solved this problem by fixing the handshake code I was using. So now a write never fails. :)